# Can UMDF drivers be packaged/shipped via WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, driver, wix3, umdf

I put together a WiX 3.0 package, utilizing the DIFx extensions, with the intentions to 
install a Windows 7 Sensor (UMDF driver). During installation, DIFXAPP 
logged "No matching devices found in INF" and simply threw the driver 
into storage. I read I'm to populate my INF with an appropriate 
**DriverPackageType**, but according to [MSDN's enumerated list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms790242.aspx), nothing fits.

Is UMDF driver installation a supported scenario? If not, what's the 
best practice for using WiX to install such drivers? Disassembling the DIfx extension shows intent to support Co-installer packages, I have yet to try 3.5 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WiX toolset just uses the DIFx custom actions provided by the DIFX team. You need to follow up with the DIFX team to understand why it doesn't like your driver.